# Issue with adding SES permissions to Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-ses

I am very new to Terraform, so still finding my way around at the moment.

I am needing to add SES permissions to a Lambda function, for sending emails.

I thought it would be as simple as adding the DynamoDB permissions, but there seems to be a different format `aws_ses_identity_policy` instead of `aws_iam_policy_attachment`, and as a result, in the `todo problem line`, I can’t seem to just use `.arn` to link the policy to the `Role`.

Is there a different way of doing this? Am I looking at older versions of the library? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
### DynamoDB
…

resource "aws_iam_policy" "DynamoDBCrudPolicy" {
  name = "DynamoDBCrudPolicy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.dynamodbPolicyDocument.json
}

### SES

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "sesPolicyDocument" {
  statement {
  actions = ["SES:SendEmail", "SES:SendRawEmail"]
  resources = [aws_ses_domain_identity.SESPolicy.arn]

  principals {
  identifiers = ["*"]
  type = "AWS"
  }
  }
}

resource "aws_ses_domain_identity" "SESPolicyDomainID" {
  domain = "example.com"
}

resource "aws_ses_identity_policy" "SESPolicy" {
  identity = aws_ses_domain_identity.SESPolicyDomainID.arn
  name = "SESPolicy"
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.sesPolicyDocument.json
}


## Attach Policies to Role

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "DynamoDBCrudPolicy_iam_policy_attachment" {
  name = "DynamoDBCrudPolicy_iam_policy_attachment"
  roles = [ aws_iam_role.DomainRole.name ]
  policy_arn = aws_iam_policy.DynamoDBCrudPolicy.arn
}

resource "aws_iam_policy_attachment" "SES_iam_policy_attachment" {
  name = "SESPolicy_iam_policy_attachment"
  roles = [ aws_iam_role.DomainRole.name ]

  # Todo problem here
  policy_arn = aws_ses_identity_policy.SESPolicy.arn
}
```

Comment: Can you add the error you are getting?

Comment: My IDE is telling me that the `arn` key of `aws_ses_identity_policy.SESPolicy.arn` is not valid

Comment: Meaning that `terraform validate` does not work?

Comment: I’ll check that